# Creating a tutorial with a link that takes the user to the next pointer

Tags: jquery, arrays, hyperlink

I am creating a tutorial for my users where a popup appears, it guides the user on how to use the site:

[image]

The pointers are in an array:

```
var wp_button_pointer_array = new Array();
wp_button_pointer_array[1] = {
    'element' : 'title',
    'options' : {
        'content': 'Here is how to do this... <a href="#" id="wp-button-pointer" class="wp-button-pointer-open-next">Next</a>', 
        'position': {'edge': 'top', 'align': 'center'} 
    } 
}; 
wp_button_pointer_array[2] = { 
    'element' : 'excerpt', 
    'options' : { 
        'content': 'Here is how to do this... <a href="#" id="wp-button-pointer" class="wp-button-pointer-open-next">Next</a>', 
        'position': {'edge': 'top', 'align': 'center'} 
    }
};
```

And here is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    jQuery('.wp-button-pointer-open-next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(typeof(jQuery().pointer) != 'undefined') { // make sure the pointer class exists

            if(jQuery('.wp-pointer').is(":visible")) { // if a pointer is already open...
                var openid = jQuery('.wp-pointer:visible').attr("id").replace('wp-pointer-',''); // ... note its id
                jQuery('#' + wp_button_pointer_array[openid].element).pointer('close'); // ... and close it
                var pointerid = parseInt(openid) + 1;
            } else {
                var pointerid = 1; // ... otherwise we want to open the first pointer
            }

            if(wp_button_pointer_array[pointerid] != undefined) { // check if next pointer exists
                jQuery('#' + wp_button_pointer_array[pointerid].element).pointer(wp_button_pointer_array[pointerid].options).pointer('open');   // and open it
                var nextid = pointerid + 1;
                if(wp_button_pointer_array[nextid] != undefined) { // check if another next pointer exists
                    jQuery('#wp-pointer-' + pointerid + " .wp-pointer-buttons").append('Next'); // and if so attach a "next" link to the current pointer
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Whenever the user click on a link with class `wp-button-pointer-open-next`, the popup pointer is supposed to change to the next pointer in the array. However, it is not changing. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: The problem may be with the link:

```
<a href="#" id="wp-button-pointer" class="wp-button-pointer-open-next">Next</a>
```

Do I need to add the ID of the pointer somewhere there?

Comment: The first if condition is missing something. If you want to check the clicked element, you need to put "this" into the jquery object. `jQuery(this).pointer`

Answer (score 1):

All the pointer anchors seem to have the same id, which makes it impossible to access them correctly with JavaScript/jQuery. Try giving them id's with an increasing counter at the end (#wp-pointer-1, #wp-pointer-2, etc..). Because the html of the anchors in the array all have the same id, the jQuery can't filter that out and use it for getting the next array item.

Also, the id's don't contain "wp-pointer-", they contain "wp-button-pointer".

Comment: Can you please update your answer with how I would do this using my code as a reference?

Comment: I guess I must have been mistaking. Not with the duplicate ID's, but with the search and replace on "#wp-pointer-". Are these the wrapping elements for the .wp-button-pointers? Because that part of the code is missing here. Maybe you can make a jsFiddel?